# str.split to json with names

Tags: javascript, json

I have taken a string that is `"title:artist"` and used `str.split` :

```
res = song.split(":");
```

Which gives me an output of :

```
["Ruby","Kaiser Chiefs"]
```

I was wondering how I could add name to this so that it appears as :

```
["name":"Ruby", "artist":"Kaiser Chiefs"]
```

Comment: so the original string looks like `Ruby:Kaiser Chiefs` ?

Comment: Also, I don't think the output is valid JSON. You probably meant `{ "name": "Ruby", "artist": "Kaiser Chiefs" }`

Answer (score 1):

`["name":"Ruby", "artist":"Kaiser Chiefs"]` isn't a valid format I guess you want to create an object so you could use just the split like :

```js
var my_string = "Ruby:Kaiser Chiefs";
var my_string_arr = my_string.split(':');
var my_object = {'name': my_string_arr[0],"artist": my_string_arr[1]};

console.log(my_object);
```

Or also assign the values to the attributes separately like:

```js
var my_string = "Ruby:Kaiser Chiefs";
var my_string_arr = my_string.split(':');
var my_object = {};

my_object.name = my_string_arr[0];
my_object.artist = my_string_arr[1];

console.log(my_object);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = song.split(':');
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({ name: res[0], artist: res[1] });
```

You can find more information about how to use JSON.stringify [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) but basically what it does is takes a JavaScript object (see how I'm passing the data as an object in my answer) and serializes it into a JSON string.

Be aware that the output is not exactly as you have described in your question. What you have is both invalid JavaScript and invalid JSON. The output that I have provided will look more along the lines of `{"name":"Ruby", "artist":"Kaiser Chiefs"}`. Notice how there is `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I tried a few variations of that as well. Your help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If this helped you please upvote it or mark it as the correct answer for future readers. I see this is your first post so welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you. I did, but it doesn't show because I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Xufox I added a link to JSON.stringify. I wasn't for sure what else to really add to explain it better.

Comment: @adam-beck This is better. I would also add that this code creates an object, which is what the OP is looking for. Maybe also that the OP’s syntax for said object was wrong. The creation of the `name` and `artist` properties might be obvious enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is: **Object**. Here is how you do it:

```js
var str = "Ruby:Kaiser Chiefs";

var res = str.split(':');

// this is how to declare an object
var myObj = {};

// this is one way to assigne to an object
// using: myObj["key"] = value;
myObj["name"] = res[0];

// this is another way to assign to an object
// using: myObj.key = value;
myObj.artist = res[1];

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: An object literal with both properties already in place is easier: `{name: …, artist: …}`.